# Linq to Entities add Where clause for EXISTS lookup in another table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, exists

Using Linq to Entities, I have an `IQueryable<T>` and want to add another WHERE clause to it that is equivalent to an `EXISTS` clause in SQL. I do not need to actually pull any data from the other table, just check if a condition is met to filter the results. Here is my latest attempt:

```
IQueryable<FileEntity> files = repository.Files.Where(...);
// More stuff done to files

files = files.Where(f => repository.FileInfo.Where(i => i.Foo == "bar")
                                            .Select(i => t.FileId)
                                            .Contains(f => f.FileId));
var list = files.ToList(); // ERROR!
```

I have also tried things like:

```
files = files.Where(f => repository.FileInfo.Any(i => i.FileId == f.FileId));
```

The exception in any case is the ol' "Unable to create a constant value of type 'FileInfo'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

How do you achieve this type of query on the database server?

Comment: Thanks for posting the error message in the second example. Could you also do it for the first one?

Comment: @Mark - Same exact error in both cases. The exception is thrown when you call something like `ToList` that executes the query.

Comment: Is FileInfo entity from DB or just a class? If it is not an entity - you can do it in a loop for every FileInfo entries.

Comment: for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx, see Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported

Comment: @Val - FileInfo is an entity, an `IQueryable<FileInfo>` that is ultimately a `DbSet<FileInfo>` from the same context as `Files`

Comment: @Joanna - But where are the queries above doing that? That's my confusion.

Comment: I could try to make a projection of FileInfo.Id into list of scalars and then use that list in your Where(...)

Comment: @Val - Please add this as an answer; that will be the best solution in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IQueryable<FileEntity> files = repository.Files.Where(...);
// More stuff done to files
var ids = repository.FileInfo.Select(i=>i.FileId).ToList();

var list = files.Where(f => ids.Contains(f.FileId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, one option would be to use a join:

```
files = files.Join(repository.FileInfo.Where(i => i.Foo == "bar"),
                   f => f.FileId,
                   i => i.FileId,
                   (f, i) => f)
             .Distinct();
```

I wouldn't expect that to necessarily translate to an EXISTS query in SQL, but have a look at the query plan and it may well be doing the same thing...

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. It seemed to be working, but made the SQL really, really, really nasty. (Almost tripled in size.)

Comment: @DaveMateer: But how did that translate into query execution plan changes? The solution you've accepted (two queries) requires data to be fetched from the database then passed back to it - *if* you end up with a lot of matching files, that could be quite painful. Maybe it's not an issue in your particular context, but it's worth considering.

Comment: You're observation is correct, and that is the factor that made the difference in my case. I expect the "pseudo-exists" query to return, on average, only a few records. It might be kind of a wash performance-wise, but the other solution seems more intuitive to me, and hopefully to the person maintaining the code down the road! I'm afraid I'd forget in a few months, "Why am I doing a join, projecting the results to eliminate the joined table, then getting distinct records?" I'd still like an actual, real "EXISTS" option in Linq to Entities, but I guess that just isn't an option at this point.

Comment: For reference: Using EF Core 2.0, this answer generates a short readable SQL statement.